# how to get find another model values from another model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I want to find user model values and want to store that value in my current blog model

```
exports.getAllBlogs = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const blogs = await Blog.find()
      .sort({ created_at: -1 })
      .populate({
        path: "comments"
      })
      .exec();
    const myblogs = blogs.map(async blog => {
      const user = await User.findOne({ _id: blog.author });
      return (blog.authorName = user.name);
    });
    console.log(myblogs);

    if (blogs.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "No Blogs Found" });
    }

    return res.status(200).json(myblogs);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);

    res.status(500).json({ error: "Something went wrong" });
  }
};
```

But this is returning me [ Promise {  } ]
for every collection

How can i achieve this oris there better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the related info with populate without needing map.

```js
exports.getAllBlogs = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const blogs = await Blog.find({})
      .sort({ created_at: -1 })
      .populate("author", "-password")
      .populate({
        path: "comments",
        populate: {
          path: "user",
          select: "-password"
        }
      });

    return res.status(200).json(blogs);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Something went wrong" });
  }
};
```

This will give a sample result like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e53b2896f41c765fc4defa1",
        "title": "Blog2 Title",
        "body": "Blog2 Body",
        "author": {
            "_id": "5e53b1726f41c765fc4def9c",
            "email": "user1@gmail.com",
            "name": "User1",
            "created_at": "2020-02-24T11:20:18.343Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-02-24T11:20:18.343Z",
            "id": "5e53b1726f41c765fc4def9c"
        },
        "created_at": "2020-02-24T11:24:57.078Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-02-24T11:24:57.078Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "comments": [
            {
                "_id": "5e53b34c6f41c765fc4defa5",
                "body": "Comment3 (user2 on user1's blog2)",
                "user": {
                    "_id": "5e53b1906f41c765fc4def9d",
                    "email": "user2@gmail.com",
                    "name": "User2",
                    "created_at": "2020-02-24T11:20:48.070Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-02-24T11:20:48.070Z",
                    "__v": 0,
                    "id": "5e53b1906f41c765fc4def9d"
                },
                "blog": "5e53b2896f41c765fc4defa1",
                "created_at": "2020-02-24T11:28:12.551Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-02-24T11:28:12.551Z"
            }
        ],
        "id": "5e53b2896f41c765fc4defa1"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e53b26c6f41c765fc4def9f",
        "title": "Blog1 Title",
        "body": "Blog1 Body",
        "author": {
            "_id": "5e53b1726f41c765fc4def9c",
            "email": "user1@gmail.com",
            "name": "User1",
            "created_at": "2020-02-24T11:20:18.343Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-02-24T11:20:18.343Z",
            "id": "5e53b1726f41c765fc4def9c"
        },
        "created_at": "2020-02-24T11:24:28.895Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-02-24T11:24:28.895Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "comments": [
            {
                "_id": "5e53b2f86f41c765fc4defa3",
                "body": "Comment1 (user2 on user1's blog1)",
                "user": {
                    "_id": "5e53b1906f41c765fc4def9d",
                    "email": "user2@gmail.com",
                    "name": "User2",
                    "created_at": "2020-02-24T11:20:48.070Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-02-24T11:20:48.070Z",
                    "id": "5e53b1906f41c765fc4def9d"
                },
                "blog": "5e53b26c6f41c765fc4def9f",
                "created_at": "2020-02-24T11:26:48.506Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-02-24T11:26:48.506Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e53b3246f41c765fc4defa4",
                "body": "Comment2 (user3 on user1's blog1)",
                "user": {
                    "_id": "5e53b1996f41c765fc4def9e",
                    "email": "user3@gmail.com",
                    "name": "User3",
                    "created_at": "2020-02-24T11:20:57.488Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-02-24T11:20:57.488Z",
                    "id": "5e53b1996f41c765fc4def9e"
                },
                "blog": "5e53b26c6f41c765fc4def9f",
                "created_at": "2020-02-24T11:27:32.305Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-02-24T11:27:32.305Z"
            }
        ],
        "id": "5e53b26c6f41c765fc4def9f"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use async in map. And that returns array of Promises.

Try this

```js
const myblogs = await Promise.all(
  blogs.map(async blog => {
      const user = await User.findOne({ _id: blog.author });
      blog.authorName = user.name;
      return blog;
   })
);
```

Comment: this works but now i am only getting names and then i change somecode        
` const myblogs = await Promise.all(
      blogs.map(async blog => {
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: blog.author });
        blog.author = user.name;

        return blog;
      })
    );` but it's not returning the value it returing the same values is there any better way to achieve this like querying or something which can get every blog author name on as well as id?

Comment: `blog.authorName = user.name` is not the same `blog.author = user.name; return blog;`. may be it's mistake? and you need `blog.**authorName** = user.name; return blog;`